# setting width of a td element using CSS id

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, column-width

I am developing an app in Django.

I am trying to set the width of the last column of my table equal to 10 pixels.

So I tryed by both including `style="width: 10 px"` in the `td` element and by using a CSS file that targets the `id` attribute given to the `td` element.

Here is my CSS file content (it's properly liked to my template, I am sure):

```
#url_cell{
  width: 10px;
}
```

And here is my template:

```
<table>

    <tr style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;width:100px">

        <td class="class_Tabella_Head">Lemma</td>
        <td class="class_Tabella_Head">Acronimo</td>
        <td class="class_Tabella_Head">Definizione</td>
        <td class="class_Tabella_Head">Titolo documento fonte</td>
        <td id="url_cell" style="width: 10 px" class="class_Tabella_Head">URL documento fonte</td>

    </tr>

{% for row in queryresult_key %}

    <tr>        

        <td class="class_Tabella_Risultati">{{ row.0 }}</td>
        <td class="class_Tabella_Risultati">{{ row.1 }}</td>
        <td class="class_Tabella_Risultati">{{ row.2 }}</td>
        <td class="class_Tabella_Risultati">{{ row.3 }}</td>
        <td id="url_cell" style="width: 10 px" class="class_Tabella_Risultati">{{ row.4 }}</td>

    </tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: You may need to set the table to: `table-layout:fixed;` , and then set the `td` width to 10px.

Comment: I tryed to add table { table-layout: fixed; } in my CSS file but it does not work.

Comment: @Tms91 because table should has defined `width`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

table tr td:last-child {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center">

    <td class="class_Tabella_Head">Lemma</td>
    <td class="class_Tabella_Head">Acronimo</td>
    <td class="class_Tabella_Head">Definizione</td>
    <td class="class_Tabella_Head">Titolo documento fonte</td>
    <td class="class_Tabella_Head">URL documento fonte</td>

  </tr>


</table>
```

You can use `:last-child` selector to access last element from the list:

```
table tr td:last-child { width: 10px }
```

UPDATE:
As Bryan Elliott mentioned you also need to add fixed layout to table:

```
table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

Comment: the solution was just to add in CSS table {  table-layout: fixed;   width: 400px; } and then #url_cell{   width: 10px; word-wrap:break-word;  }